# How to clean a string and extract number postfixes in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, regex, t-sql

I have a string that consists of a name and in most cases it has a postfix with one or two numbers at the end. This number-postfix should be cut off from the name. One number represents a status and should be extracted. If there are two numbers it is the seconde from the right, if there is one number it is the first from the right. These numbers are seperated by an underscore. Underscores can also be used within the name.
The result should be a column with the clearname and the extracted status.

I tried to solve the problem with the standard string functions like Substring, Charindex, Patindex, LEN and son on. But my approach became very bulky quickly and hard to maintain. I wonder if there is an elegant solution with the usual SQl-Server capabilities (if possible without installing extras for regex).

```
SELECT _data.myStr
    -- , ... AS clearname  /*String cleaned from number_postfixes*/
    -- , ... AS Status     /*second number from the right*/
FROM (
    SELECT 'tree_leafs_offer_2_1' AS myStr  --clearname: tree_leafs_offer; cut off: _2_1; extracted status: 2
        UNION
    SELECT 'tree_leafs_offer_2_10' AS myStr --clearname: tree_leafs_offer_2_10; cut off: _2_10; extracted status: 2
        UNION
    SELECT 'tree_leafs_offer_2_2' AS myStr  --clearname: tree_leafs_offer; cut off: _2_2; extracted status: 2
        UNION
    SELECT 'tree_leafs_offer_1150_1' AS myStr   --clearname: tree_leafs_offer; cut off: _1150_1; extracted status: 1150
        UNION
    SELECT 'tree_leafs_offer_1150_10' AS myStr  --clearname: tree_leafs_offer; cut off: _1150_10; extracted status: 1150
        UNION
    SELECT 'builder_bundle_less_xl_1' AS myStr  --clearname: builder_bundle_less_xl; cut off: _1; extracted status: 1
        UNION
    SELECT 'builder_bundle_less_xl_10' AS myStr --clearname: builder_bundle_less_xl; cut off: _10; extracted status: 10
        UNION
    SELECT 'static_components_wolves_10_4' AS myStr --clearname: static_components_wolves; cut off: _10_4; extracted status: 4
        UNION
    SELECT 'coke_0_boring_components_bundle_grant_1' AS myStr   --clearname: oke_0_boring_components_bundle_grant; cut off: _1; extracted status: 1
        UNION
    SELECT 'coke_0_soccer18_end_1_4h_101' AS myStr  --clearname: coke_0_soccer18_end_1_4h; cut off: _101; extracted status: 101
        UNION
    SELECT 'coke_0_late_downsell_bundle_high_114' AS myStr  --clearname: coke_0_late_downsell_bundle_high; cut off: _114; extracted status: 114
        UNION
    SELECT 'itembundle_mine_bundle_small' AS myStr  --clearname: itembundle_mine_bundle_small; cut off: <nothing>; extracted status: NULL
) AS _data
```

```
As-Is Result:
-----------------
myStr:
---------------------------------------
builder_bundle_less_xl_1
builder_bundle_less_xl_10
coke_0_boring_components_bundle_grant_1
coke_0_late_downsell_bundle_high_114
coke_0_soccer18_end_1_4h_101
itembundle_mine_bundle_small
static_components_wolves_10_4
tree_leafs_offer_1150_1
tree_leafs_offer_1150_10
tree_leafs_offer_2_1
tree_leafs_offer_2_10
tree_leafs_offer_2_2

To-Be Result (two new columns):
-------------------
clearname:                              |Status
----------------------------------------------
builder_bundle_less_xl                  |   1
builder_bundle_less_xl                  |  10
coke_0_boring_components_bundle_grant   |   1
coke_0_late_downsell_bundle_high        | 114
coke_0_soccer18_end_1_4h                | 101
itembundle_mine_bundle_small            |NULL
static_components_wolves                |  10
tree_leafs_offer                        |1150
tree_leafs_offer                        |1150
tree_leafs_offer                        |   2
tree_leafs_offer                        |   2
tree_leafs_offer                        |   2
```

Comment: Is this a one-off task?

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: It is SQl Server 2016.

Comment: It is not a one-off task, it will be part of an ETL process that runs on a regular base. But It is not so much data (3500 rows) so perfomance should not be a big issue.

Comment: Egad!!! I just realized the number you want as output when there are more than one number at the end. What if there are three in a row at the end? What about four? This data is painful to say the least. Is there a chance you can change the source of this data instead of being forced to wrangle this?

Comment: Yep, it is a pain to wrangle this. But It is max two numbers from the right. Like the sample data. (If there are more they can be ignored or it can be shit-in shit-out).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest: this format is awful! If this is not a *one-time-action* you really should try to change this **before** you have to deal with it.

But - if you have to stick with this - you might give this a try:

**EDIT**: resolved a bad computation of the status position...

```sql
DECLARE  @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,myStr VARCHAR(1000));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('tree_leafs_offer_2_1')
,('tree_leafs_offer_2_10')
,('tree_leafs_offer_2_2')
,('tree_leafs_offer_1150_1')
,('tree_leafs_offer_1150_10')
,('builder_bundle_less_xl_1')
,('builder_bundle_less_xl_10')
,('static_components_wolves_10_4')
,('coke_0_boring_components_bundle_grant_1')
,('coke_0_soccer18_end_1_4h_101')
,('coke_0_late_downsell_bundle_high_114')
,('itembundle_mine_bundle_small');
```

The query

```sql
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT t.ID
          ,t.myStr 
            ,A.[key] AS Position
            ,A.[value] AS WordFragment
            ,B.CastedToInt
    FROM @tbl t
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(N'["' + REPLACE(t.myStr,'_','","') + '"]') A
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT TRY_CAST(A.[value] AS INT)) B(CastedToInt)
) 
SELECT ID
      ,myStr
        ,STUFF(
        (SELECT CONCAT('_',cte2.WordFragment)
        FROM cte cte2
        WHERE cte2.ID=cte.ID
            AND cte2.Position<=A.PositionHighestNonInt
        ORDER BY cte2.Position
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ),1,1,'') AS ClearName
        ,(SELECT cte3.CastedToInt FROM cte cte3 WHERE cte3.ID=cte.ID AND cte3.Position=A.PositionHighestNonInt+1) AS [Status]
FROM cte
CROSS APPLY (
                 SELECT ISNULL(MAX(x.Position),1000) 
                 FROM cte x 
                 WHERE x.ID=cte.ID AND x.CastedToInt IS NULL
             ) A(PositionHighestNonInt)
GROUP BY ID,myStr,PositionHighestNonInt;
```

The result

```
+----+---------------------------------------+--------+
| ID | ClearName                             | Status |
+----+---------------------------------------+--------+
| 1  | tree_leafs_offer                      | 2      |
+----+---------------------------------------+--------+
| 2  | tree_leafs_offer                      | 2      |
+----+---------------------------------------+--------+
| 3  | tree_leafs_offer                      | 2      |
+----+---------------------------------------+--------+
| 4  | tree_leafs_offer                      | 1150   |
+----+---------------------------------------+--------+
| 5  | tree_leafs_offer                      | 1150   |
+----+---------------------------------------+--------+
| 6  | builder_bundle_less_xl                | 1      |
+----+---------------------------------------+--------+
| 7  | builder_bundle_less_xl                | 10     |
+----+---------------------------------------+--------+
| 8  | static_components_wolves              | 10     |
+----+---------------------------------------+--------+
| 9  | coke_0_boring_components_bundle_grant | 1      |
+----+---------------------------------------+--------+
| 10 | coke_0_soccer18_end_1_4h              | 101    |
+----+---------------------------------------+--------+
| 11 | coke_0_late_downsell_bundle_high      | 114    |
+----+---------------------------------------+--------+
| 12 | itembundle_mine_bundle_small          | NULL   |
+----+---------------------------------------+--------+
```

The idea:

- Provide your data in a *mockup table*
- Use a trick with `OPENJSON` to get the string split and find parts which can be cast to `INT`.
- Find the highest *non-int* fragment. The `Status` will be the next index
- With v2017 you could use `STRING_AGG`, but with v2016 we have to use a XML-based trick to concatenate all fragments **before** the `[Status]`.

Comment: Aside from the the solution being spot on, your initial comment is more important.   +1

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach is to use string replacement and `JSON` capabilities of SQL Server 2016+. Each row is reversed and transformed into a valid JSON array (`'tree_leafs_offer_2_1'` is transformed into `'["1","2","reffo","sfael","eert"]'` for example). Then you can easily check if the first and the second items are valid numbers using `JSON_VALUE(<json_array>, '$[0]')`, `JSON_VALUE(<json_array>, '$[1]')` and `TRY_CONVERT()`. This will work if you have maximum two numbers from the right.

Input:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (
   myStr varchar(max)
)
INSERT INTO #Data 
   (MyStr)
VALUES   
   ('tree_leafs_offer_2_1'),
   ('tree_leafs_offer_2_10'),
   ('tree_leafs_offer_2_2'),
   ('tree_leafs_offer_1150_1'),
   ('tree_leafs_offer_1150_10'),
   ('builder_bundle_less_xl_1'),
   ('builder_bundle_less_xl_10'),
   ('static_components_wolves_10_4'),
   ('coke_0_boring_components_bundle_grant_1'),
   ('coke_0_soccer18_end_1_4h_101'),
   ('coke_0_late_downsell_bundle_high_114'),
   ('itembundle_mine_bundle_small')
```

T-SQL:

```
SELECT 
   LEFT(myStr, LEN(myStr) - CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(myStr))) as ClearName,
   REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(myStr), CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(myStr)) - 1)) AS Status
FROM (
   SELECT 
      CASE 
         WHEN 
            TRY_CONVERT(int, REVERSE(JSON_VALUE(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(STRING_ESCAPE(REVERSE(MyStr), 'json'), '_', '","'), '"]'), '$[1]'))) IS NULL AND
            TRY_CONVERT(int, REVERSE(JSON_VALUE(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(STRING_ESCAPE(REVERSE(MyStr), 'json'), '_', '","'), '"]'), '$[0]'))) IS NULL
            THEN CONCAT(myStr, '_0') 
         WHEN 
            TRY_CONVERT(int, REVERSE(JSON_VALUE(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(STRING_ESCAPE(REVERSE(MyStr), 'json'), '_', '","'), '"]'), '$[1]'))) IS NULL AND 
            TRY_CONVERT(int, REVERSE(JSON_VALUE(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(STRING_ESCAPE(REVERSE(MyStr), 'json'), '_', '","'), '"]'), '$[0]'))) IS NOT NULL
            THEN MyStr 
         ELSE LEFT(myStr, LEN(myStr) - CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(myStr)))
      END AS myStr      
   FROM #Data
) fixed
ORDER BY MyStr
```

Output:

```
----------------------------------------------
ClearName                               Status
----------------------------------------------
builder_bundle_less_xl                  1
builder_bundle_less_xl                  10
coke_0_boring_components_bundle_grant   1
coke_0_late_downsell_bundle_high        114
coke_0_soccer18_end_1_4h                101
itembundle_mine_bundle_small            0
static_components_wolves                10
tree_leafs_offer                        1150
tree_leafs_offer                        1150
tree_leafs_offer                        2
tree_leafs_offer                        2
tree_leafs_offer                        2
```